# Access to global variable after calling NdisAcquireSpinLock causes IRQL_NOT_LESS_OR_EQUAL BSoD

Tags: c, windows, driver, ndis, irql

I have a `NDIS Filter driver` (a update for WinPcap) and tested it on Windows 10 10586 x64 VM. I enabled the verifier and it causes `IRQL_NOT_LESS_OR_EQUAL` BSoD when launching Wireshark (aka using my driver's function).

Here's the dump:

```
1: kd> !analyze -v
*******************************************************************************
*                                                                             *
*                        Bugcheck Analysis                                    *
*                                                                             *
*******************************************************************************

IRQL_NOT_LESS_OR_EQUAL (a)
An attempt was made to access a pageable (or completely invalid) address at an
interrupt request level (IRQL) that is too high.  This is usually
caused by drivers using improper addresses.
If a kernel debugger is available get the stack backtrace.
Arguments:
Arg1: fffff80137694a20, memory referenced
Arg2: 0000000000000002, IRQL
Arg3: 0000000000000008, bitfield :
    bit 0 : value 0 = read operation, 1 = write operation
    bit 3 : value 0 = not an execute operation, 1 = execute operation (only on chips which support this level of status)
Arg4: fffff80137694a20, address which referenced memory

Debugging Details:
------------------

***** Debugger could not find nt in module list, module list might be corrupt, error 0x80070057.


DUMP_CLASS: 1

DUMP_QUALIFIER: 400

BUILD_VERSION_STRING:  10586.103.amd64fre.th2_release.160126-1819

SYSTEM_MANUFACTURER:  VMware, Inc.

VIRTUAL_MACHINE:  VMware

SYSTEM_PRODUCT_NAME:  VMware Virtual Platform

SYSTEM_VERSION:  None

BIOS_VENDOR:  Phoenix Technologies LTD

BIOS_VERSION:  6.00

BIOS_DATE:  07/02/2015

BASEBOARD_MANUFACTURER:  Intel Corporation

BASEBOARD_PRODUCT:  440BX Desktop Reference Platform

BASEBOARD_VERSION:  None

DUMP_TYPE:  2

BUGCHECK_P1: fffff80137694a20

BUGCHECK_P2: 2

BUGCHECK_P3: 8

BUGCHECK_P4: fffff80137694a20

READ_ADDRESS: unable to get nt!MiSessionIdBitmap
Unable to get value of nt!MiSessionWsList
 fffff80137694a20 

CURRENT_IRQL:  0

FAULTING_IP: 
+0
fffff801`37694a20 4883ec08        sub     rsp,8

CPU_COUNT: 2

CPU_MHZ: 961

CPU_VENDOR:  GenuineIntel

CPU_FAMILY: 6

CPU_MODEL: 3c

CPU_STEPPING: 3

CPU_MICROCODE: 0,0,0,0 (F,M,S,R)  SIG: 1E'00000000 (cache) 0'00000000 (init)

CUSTOMER_CRASH_COUNT:  1

DEFAULT_BUCKET_ID:  CORRUPT_MODULELIST_AV

BUGCHECK_STR:  AV

ANALYSIS_SESSION_HOST:  AKISN0W-PC

ANALYSIS_SESSION_TIME:  03-18-2016 09:48:01.0434

ANALYSIS_VERSION: 10.0.10586.567 amd64fre

LAST_CONTROL_TRANSFER:  from fffff801373c7fe9 to fffff801373bd480

FAILED_INSTRUCTION_ADDRESS: 
+0
fffff801`37694a20 4883ec08        sub     rsp,8

SYMBOL_ON_RAW_STACK:  1

STACK_ADDR_RAW_STACK_SYMBOL: ffffd0012ba372e8

STACK_COMMAND:  dps ffffd0012ba372e8-0x20 ; kb

STACK_TEXT:  
ffffd001`2ba372c8  fffff801`376876d6
ffffd001`2ba372d0  fffff801`3792eebe
ffffd001`2ba372d8  fffff801`372ef2c2
ffffd001`2ba372e0  fffff800`71272b02 npf!NPF_GetCopyFromOpenArray+0x22 [j:\npcap\packetwin7\npf\npf\openclos.c @ 1084]
ffffd001`2ba372e8  fffff800`71272ec5 npf!NPF_OpenAdapter+0x2d [j:\npcap\packetwin7\npf\npf\openclos.c @ 258]
ffffd001`2ba372f0  00000000`00000000
ffffd001`2ba372f8  00000000`00000000
ffffd001`2ba37300  00000000`00000000
ffffd001`2ba37308  00000000`00000000
ffffd001`2ba37310  fffff801`37694a20
ffffd001`2ba37318  fffff800`71272ec5 npf!NPF_OpenAdapter+0x2d [j:\npcap\packetwin7\npf\npf\openclos.c @ 258]
ffffd001`2ba37320  fffff801`3792eebe
ffffd001`2ba37328  fffff801`372ef2c2
ffffd001`2ba37330  fffff801`37690d68
ffffd001`2ba37338  fffff801`376876d6
ffffd001`2ba37340  fffff801`376860dc


FOLLOWUP_IP: 
npf!NPF_GetCopyFromOpenArray+22 [j:\npcap\packetwin7\npf\npf\openclos.c @ 1084]
fffff800`71272b02 488b1d177e0000  mov     rbx,qword ptr [npf!g_arrOpen (fffff800`7127a920)]

FAULT_INSTR_CODE:  171d8b48

FAULTING_SOURCE_LINE:  j:\npcap\packetwin7\npf\npf\openclos.c

FAULTING_SOURCE_FILE:  j:\npcap\packetwin7\npf\npf\openclos.c

FAULTING_SOURCE_LINE_NUMBER:  1084

FAULTING_SOURCE_CODE:  
  1080:     POPEN_INSTANCE CurOpen;
  1081:     TRACE_ENTER();
  1082: 
  1083:     NdisAcquireSpinLock(&g_OpenArrayLock);
> 1084:     for (CurOpen = g_arrOpen; CurOpen != NULL; CurOpen = CurOpen->Next)
  1085:     {
  1086:         if (CurOpen->AdapterBindingStatus == ADAPTER_BOUND && NPF_EqualAdapterName(&CurOpen->AdapterName, pAdapterName) == TRUE)
  1087:         {
  1088:             NdisReleaseSpinLock(&g_OpenArrayLock);
  1089:             return NPF_DuplicateOpenObject(CurOpen, DeviceExtension);


SYMBOL_NAME:  npf!NPF_GetCopyFromOpenArray+22

FOLLOWUP_NAME:  MachineOwner

DEBUG_FLR_IMAGE_TIMESTAMP:  0

IMAGE_VERSION:  0.6.0.301

MODULE_NAME: Unknown_Module

IMAGE_NAME:  Unknown_Image

BUCKET_ID:  CORRUPT_MODULELIST_AV

PRIMARY_PROBLEM_CLASS:  CORRUPT_MODULELIST

FAILURE_BUCKET_ID:  CORRUPT_MODULELIST_AV

TARGET_TIME:  2016-03-18T01:43:34.000Z

OSBUILD:  10586

OSSERVICEPACK:  0

SERVICEPACK_NUMBER: 0

OS_REVISION: 0

SUITE_MASK:  272

PRODUCT_TYPE:  1

OSPLATFORM_TYPE:  x64

OSNAME:  Windows 10

OSEDITION:  Windows 10 WinNt TerminalServer SingleUserTS

OS_LOCALE:  

USER_LCID:  0

OSBUILD_TIMESTAMP:  unknown_date

BUILDDATESTAMP_STR:  160126-1819

BUILDLAB_STR:  th2_release

BUILDOSVER_STR:  10.0.10586.103.amd64fre.th2_release.160126-1819

ANALYSIS_SESSION_ELAPSED_TIME: 18d9

ANALYSIS_SOURCE:  KM

FAILURE_ID_HASH_STRING:  km:corrupt_modulelist_av

FAILURE_ID_HASH:  {fc259191-ef0c-6215-476f-d32e5dcaf1b7}

Followup:     MachineOwner
---------
```

The faulty source code is here: https://github.com/nmap/npcap/blob/master/packetWin7/npf/npf/Openclos.c

I know `NdisAcquireSpinLock` call will raise IRQL to `Dispatch_LEVEL`. And WinDbg seems to say that `g_arrOpen` is in a pageable memory which is not allowed to be accessed in `Dispatch_LEVEL`. However, the truth is, `g_arrOpen` is a global variable pointed to the `OPEN_INSTANCE` struct. `OPEN_INSTANCE` instances are allocated in Non-paged pool. A global variable coexists with the driver image, so it can't be paged out either.

So I don't what's wrong here? Any help? Thanks!

Comment: *A global variable coexists with the driver image, so it can't be paged out either.* - that's not true, the driver image can include pageable sections.  I'm not sure offhand whether global variables are pageable by default, but it wouldn't be particularly surprising.

Comment: @HarryJohnston, According to: https://www.osronline.com/showthread.cfm?link=155166, the global variable in a driver is **Non-paged** by default, if not specified ``data_seg("PAGE")`` or the similar pragma.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The global variable isn't the problem.  Firstly, note that `Arg3` has the execute bit set, i.e., the paged out memory is code, not data.  You can confirm this by noting that `READ_ADDRESS` and `FAULTING_IP` are the same.

So, let's look at that code more closely:

```
> 1084:     for (CurOpen = g_arrOpen; CurOpen != NULL; CurOpen = CurOpen->Next)
  1085:     {
  1086:         if (CurOpen->AdapterBindingStatus == ADAPTER_BOUND && NPF_EqualAdapterName(&CurOpen->AdapterName, pAdapterName) == TRUE)
```

This is a release build, so you can't take the indicated line too seriously; the problem is however likely to be nearby.  A page fault for executable data suggests a bad function call, so let's start by looking at `NPF_EqualAdapterName`:

```
BOOLEAN
NPF_EqualAdapterName(
    PNDIS_STRING s1,
    PNDIS_STRING s2
    )
{
    // return RtlEqualMemory(s1->Buffer, s2->Buffer, s2->Length);
    // We use RtlEqualUnicodeString because it's case-insensitive. However, verifier will complain about this call because it's under DISPATCH_LEVEL.
    // Just don't enable the IRQL switch when testing with verifier.
    return RtlEqualUnicodeString(s1, s2, TRUE);
}
```

A very short function, so almost certainly inlined, so it wouldn't necessarily turn up in the stack trace.  That leads us to the call to `RtlEqualUnicodeString` which when we [check the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff561854(v=vs.85).aspx) turns out to require PASSIVE_LEVEL.  Bingo.  (Heck, we didn't even need to look at the documentation except for verification, since the *comments outright state that the call is illegal.*)

Conclusion: `RtlEqualUnicodeString` happened to be paged out at the time you called it.

(At a guess, the best solution would be to go back to using `RtlEqualMemory` and make sure that your comparison string is properly cased ahead of time.)

Comment: Nice dissection :) I would still be a bit caucious about the conclusion. It sounds very reasonable that this is the problem, but there are more valid options - e.g., the NPF_GetCopyFromOpenArray function itself might be in pagable section and was paged out at the moment of failure.

Comment: @SomeWittyUsername: less likely IMO, because we can see that the code doesn't declare that function to be pageable.  Not out of the question, certainly, but we *know* that `RtlEqualUnicodeString` is pageable, so I think the best bet for the OP is to fix that first and only look for other causes if the problem recurs.

Comment: Agree, just wanted to mention it's also an option. I didn't bother to look at the full source code, but if you say it's not declared pagable there then this option isn't viable :)

Comment: @SomeWittyUsername: no worries, I'd misinterpreted "more valid options" as "options that are more likely" rather than "other options that are also possible" as in retrospect I see you intended.  You suggestion is still theoretically possible, I think - we were only given the single .c file, so there might be declarations hidden away in one of the includes, and presumably you *could* make an entire module pageable in the build settings if you were so inclined.  Unwise, but not impossible. :-)